# How to extract a part of uri in spray routing

Tags: scala, routes, match, spray

I want to make a REST service and paths to user account should start with an `id` prefix, but as a part of the path itself, but like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/profile/id2314234
```

i've tried to play with PathMatcher, but didn't succeeded. How can i extract `2314234` from the uri?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the type of the representation you need, you can use a different matchers, if you need a string check the following:

```
val route = 
  path("profile" / "id" ~ Segment) { segm =>
    complete(s"$id") // in the example would return 2314234 as a string
  }
}
```

To return this as `Int` or `Long` check for other matcher [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/PathMatcher.scala#L163), but the idea is the same, you can split a part of your path with `~`